# Thread sometimes doesnt "run"

Tags: java

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    while(!interrupted()){
        String msg;
        try {
            String s = ut.getText();
        //while(s.isEmpty() || s.equals("")){
                //sleep(1000);
            //  break;
        //  }
            String v[] = s.split(" ");
            switch (v[0]){
            case "INSC":
                if(v.length==4 && ut.getEstado()==0){
                    out.println(s);
                    ut.setEstado(1);
                    ut.sendMessage("Server: Utilizador inscrito.");
                }
                else
                    ut.sendMessage("Server: Invalido!");
                break;
            case "CLT":
                if(ut.getEstado()==1) {
                    out.println(s);
                    ut.setEstado(1);
                    while((msg = in.readLine())!= null){                      
                        System.out.println(msg);
                        ut.sendMessage("Server: " + msg);
                        if(!in.ready())
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    ut.sendMessage("Server: Invalido!");    
                break;
            case "":
                break;
            default:
                ut.sendMessage("Server: Invalido!");

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So I have this thread and most of the times it runs correctly, it gets the string s and does what its in the code but sometimes it reads the string and does nothing, not even one case, it just seems to skip everything and wait for the next string.
Any suggestion or need more context?

```
public class Utilizador {

private String nome;
private String endereco;
private int porto;
private int estado;
private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea area;
private JTextField text;
private String temporary;

public Utilizador(String nome, String endereco, int porto) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.endereco = endereco;
    this.porto = porto;
    estado = 0;

}

private void creatChat() {

    area = new JTextArea(17,20);
    text = new JTextField();
    frame = new JFrame("Utilizador");
    temporary = ("");


    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
    scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));

    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)area.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    frame.add(scroll,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(text);

    area.setEditable(false);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    area.append("Utilizador Conectado!\n");

    text.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String s = text.getText();
            if(!s.equals("")){
                sendMessage("\nUtilizador: "+ s +"\n");
                text.setText("");
                temporary=s;
            }
        }
    }   
            );
}

private void open(){
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//centro
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

private void openchat(){
    creatChat();
    open();

}

public void sendMessage(String s){
    area.append(s +"\n");
}

public String getText(){
    String s = temporary;
    temporary = "";
    return s;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public int getPorto() {
    return porto;
}

public int getEstado(){ 
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(int e){
    estado = e;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Utilizador ut = new Utilizador("2134", "23145",24);
    ut.openchat();
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", Diretorio.getInstance().getPorto());
    UtilizadorThread t = new UtilizadorThread(socket, ut);
    t.start();

}
```

Added Some context, its a server-client, and i made a quick chat that updates everytime i press enter

Comment: Try adding some `sleep` time somewhere in the loop so it is kinder to other threads. If you don't sleep in a tight loop Java has a hard time doing other stuff.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what `s` contains when you get this "skip everything" behavior.

Comment: What is ut? Is ut.getText() thread safe? Do you println() something while it is in readline()? If you print something while it is in readline() the return value of readline() maybe null.

Comment: everytime i go on debugger everything works just fine

Comment: What is `ut`?  Are it's methods thread safe?

Comment: The debugger stops the thread where the current line is in. Usually that means, that you have a race condition somewhere. For example this code is not thread safe:
int i = 0; i = i + 1; here i can be 0, 1 or on complex objects just garbage. My guess is a timing issue. Race condition are hard to debug if not the complete code is present.

Comment: Added a little more context

Comment: Cant be race condition since this "error" happens with only one thread

Comment: Try to add some println() statments with the variables. I sometimes create a debug function like "debug(String input, String textfield, int other) and print them with **** value list ****. If these values are not consistent what it should you know the reason for the race condition.

Comment: Does adding the keyword `synchronized` to all methods of `Utilizador` fix your issue?

Comment: Tried adding synchronized doesnt work, just tried it